# Kotlin Login and logout using shared prefereces

Tags: android, kotlin, authentication, sharedpreferences, logout

I am using shared preferences to login and logout the user of the application. Once the user logs in, the login screen is not showed again after the application is killed and started again. But when I enter the application and go to the screen after the login page and press back button, it shows the login screen again. I don't want the login screen to be showed again even after the back button is pressed. I want it to go completely out of the aplication on pressing back button.
Here is my code for login :

```
    val sp = getSharedPreferences("login",MODE_PRIVATE)

    if (sp.getBoolean("logged", false))
    {
        login()
    }
loginButton.setOnClickListener() {

        login()
        sp.edit().putBoolean("logged", true).apply()


        Log.v("Login Msg", "Login button clicked")
 getusername = findViewById(R.id.usernameEditText)
        var username = usernameEditText.text
        Log.v("username",username.toString())

        getpass = findViewById(R.id.passEditText)
        var pass = passEditText.text
        Log.v("pass",pass.toString())  }
fun login() {
    val i = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(i)
}
```

Here is the code for logout:

```
 logoutButton.setOnClickListener(){

        logout()
        val sp = getSharedPreferences("login",MODE_PRIVATE)
        sp.edit().putBoolean("logged", false).apply()


        Log.v("Logout msg", "Logout button clicked")
    }
fun logout(){

    val i = Intent(this, LogInActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually we can override "Back Button" method in each activity.

Below I reuse your code to manage logout when back button is pressed, perhaps this is the one you are looking for

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
   super.onBackPressed()
   val sp = getSharedPreferences("login",MODE_PRIVATE)
   sp.edit().putBoolean("logged", false).apply()
   logout()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the login activity is still there in the back stack after going to the HomeActivity. To achieve your requirement you must remove everything from the back stack before going to the HomeActivity.

Replace your login function with the below function.

```
fun login() {
        val i = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        i.run {
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        }
        startActivity(i)
    }
```

Here we are basically adding a set of flags to the intent.
**Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP** clears all the view underneath the current view
**Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK** we are removing the existing tasks
**Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** we are creating a new task for the HomeActivity.

**Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK** and **Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** should be used in conjunction with each other.

Comment: This is done. Could you please help me with another question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67355044/urgent-help-required-how-to-get-values-from-json-array-with-dynamic-key-values?noredirect=1#comment119053430_67355044