# How to get values from JSON array with dynamic key-values in a for loop ? KOTLIN

Tags: android, arrays, json, kotlin

This is my JSON:

```
{"result": {
"product_id": 283946,
"shop_id": 129, 
"is_favorite": false,
"item_sold_by": "Quantity",
"item_description": "hello",
"item_size": [
  {
    "name": "Height",
    "value": "29cm"
  },
  {
    "name": "Width",
    "value": "52cm"
  }
 val json = String(responseBody, charset)

                val gson = Gson().newBuilder().serializeNulls().create()

                val itemsdetailresult = gson.fromJson<ItemDetailJson>(json, genericType<ItemDetailJson>())


                Log.v("Test1", json)

                Log.v("Test2", itemsdetailresult.toString())


                Picasso.get().load(itemsdetailresult.result.pic1).into(itempic)
                itemName.text = itemsdetailresult.result.item_name
                shopName.text = itemsdetailresult.result.shop_name
                itemdescrip.text = itemsdetailresult.result.item_description
                itemprice.text = itemsdetailresult.result.price





                val obj = JSONObject(json)
                val getObject = obj.getJSONObject("result")
                val getArray = getObject.getJSONArray("item_size")



                var itemSizeArray = ArrayList<ItemSize>()
                var itemString = ""
                   for (i in 0 until getArray.length()) {
                       val objects: JSONObject
                       objects = getArray.getJSONObject(i)

                       val name = objects["name"].toString()
                       val value = objects["value"].toString()

                       itemSizeArray.add(ItemSize(name, value))


                       itemSizeArray.forEach { data ->
                           itemString = itemString.plus("${data.name} : ${data.value}")

                       }
                   }

                itemsizename.text = itemString

                Log.v("PRINT", itemsizename.toString())

            }
```

I want the output as --> Height: 29cm / width:52cm and so on if there are more values added in the  "item_size"array. How can that be achieved in this for loop. I want to keep appending all the values of "name" and "value" in a variable(parameter) in the for loop and use this variable outside of the for loop.

Comment: Please check your JSON string, looks like it is invalid.

Comment: which one is invalid? Can you please specify ? .. This is the JSON response that I get from an API which is huge.. This is a part of the response that I'm showing with what I need to access.

Comment: Just out of interest, do you think that your problem is more important than all the rest on here? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly new here as a user. I'll edit my question. If you could please help that would help me alot, thanks

Comment: No problem, just generally puts people off answering! Regardless, the answer from @pranavjayaraj seems like it explains everything you need.

Comment: Stop knocking for people trying yo! This is a legit question! We ain't iOS developers (well most of us anyways...) so stop acting like it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you just need to create a custom data model class with the name and value variables.

```
data class ItemSizeDataModel(
val name: String?,
val value: String?
)
```

Now in the class where you are fetching the JSON make use of the ItemSizeDataModel to store the itemsize - name and value.

```
val json = String(responseBody, charset)
val obj = JSONObject(json)
val getObject = obj.getJSONObject("result")
val getArray = getObject.getJSONArray("item_size")
var parameter: String

var itemSizeArray = ArrayList<ItemSizeDataModel>()

for (i in 0 until getArray.length()) {
        val objects: JSONObject
        objects = getArray.getJSONObject(i)
        val name = objects["name"].toString()
        val Value = objects["value"].toString()
        itemSizeArray.add(ItemSizeDataModel(name = name, value = value))
      }
```

Now you can access the itemSizeArray array list and access the name and value for each index.

For the output Height: 29cm / width:52cm
you can iterate through the loop

```
var itemString = ""
itemSizeArray.forEach{data->
itemString = itemString.plus("${data.name}:${data.value}/")
}
itemString = itemString.dropLast(1)
```

Comment: I already have a class like ItemSizeDataModel since I'm parsing JSON through the model class method. I want to be able to access all of the "name" and "values" in the list of arrays as it can increase or decrease depending on the item which is why I can't give i = 0 or i = 1 or any specifc value since i can either increase, decrease or stay the same

Comment: I just want to append all the values of "name" and "value" from i in 0 until getArray.length() to a string in the loop and use that string outside of the loop

Comment: how can I display and see what all values I'm getting?

Comment: Since this is the output that I need is something like this --> Height: 29cm / width:52cm. Maybe for another item there can be Length specified too.

Comment: Please check the edited answer. Also if there is length then it will automatically get saved to the custom model arraylist. Which is finally iterated to get something like Height: 29cm / width:52cm / length: 100 cm .

Comment: I wrote the foreach part, it gives me output as :  Height: 29cm /Height: 29cm/ width:52cm. The height repeats twice. I tried debugging and checking why but I'm not able to locate the issue.

Comment: I am getting repeated values of everything. I tried checking again. No luck

Comment: Repeated values might be because either the appended string or the array was not cleared. It would be helpful if you could share the code snippet.

Comment: Sure. I will. I have an API which gives me this json response. I've parsed the JSON and set other values of what I've wanted. The code that I'm going to post is for the onsuccess part of the http get request . All the above code is written in the success  part.

Comment: The problem is you are calling the itemSizeArray.forEach{} inside the for loop, it should be called outside the for loop. You have called it inside the for loop due to which the strings are getting appended repeatedly. Call the itemSizeArray.forEach{} outside the for loop and this will solve the issue.

Comment: It works. I just want to add a "/" if there's another size else no need of that.

Comment: I tried using joinToString() here for the "/" but it doesnt work. I'm getting the output as Height: 29cm / width:52cm /  whereas I need the output as: Height: 29cm/ width:52cm.After the last size I'm still getting a "/". How can I fix this ?

Comment: You can do that by using the dropLast() function in Kotlin. I have updated it in the solution. string.dropLast(1) basically removes 1 char from the end which is '/' in our case.

Comment: It worked! Thanks alot. There's so much for me to learn since I'm a beginner. Is it okay to ask you for help again ?

Comment: Sure. Glad to help you. Also it would be great if you could upvote the solution if you found it to be helpful :)

Comment: Done ! :) . Will comment on this post again if I need some help. :)